# how can I set google drive download file's location?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

drive download is worked in ajax but I cannot find my files

I've tried

```
//      driveService.files()
//        .export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
//        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

but still cannot find my file

```
        @Override
        public int downloadFile(HttpSession session, String fileId) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Drive driveService = getCredential(session);
            OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        driveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

    //      driveService.files()
    //        .export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
    //        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            return 0;
        }
```

ajax successed and method worked without problems but cannot find downloaded file

Answer (score 1):

You've created an OutputStream which contains your file's contents. However, you do nothing with it. You need to consume that OutputStream and write it to a local file yourself.